# OpenCV OpenGLDrawCallback doesn't get called

Tags: c++, c, qt, opencv, opengl

I initialize OpenCV window with following code:

```
cv::VideoCapture * stream = new cv::VideoCapture("stream_ip");
if (!stream->isOpened()){ 
    printf("Couldn't open stream! %s\n", strerror(errno));
}

//We create window with OpenGL enabled.
cv::namedWindow("rtsp_stream", cv::WINDOW_OPENGL);

//Make it fullscreen (I also tried with fixed screen size without luck.)
cv::setWindowProperty("rtsp_stream", cv::WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv::WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

//Set OpenGL context to use this window.
cv::setOpenGlContext("rtsp_stream");

//Set openGlDrawCallback.
cv::setOpenGlDrawCallback("rtsp_stream", on_opengl, NULL);

//This is the material that the image will be rendered on.
cv::Mat frame;
char k;
bool continueStream = true;

while (continueStream) {

    //We read data from the stream and write it on the frame.
    if((stream->read(frame)) != 0){
        //Then we display/render the image using imshow.
        cv::imshow("rtsp_stream", frame);
        k = cv::waitKey(1);

        //I'm not sure if updateWindow needs to be manually called to make openGLDrawCallback or if imshow calls it automatically after done rendering. So I have tried with and without it.
        //cv::updateWindow("rtsp_stream");

        switch(k){
        case 0x1b: //ESC key
            printf("Closing stream.\n");
            continueStream = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`open_gl` function just simply fprints some text to see if opengldrawcallback gets called. I have also made sure I have OpenGL and QT enabled on my OpenCV with `std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << std::endl;`. I have tried to find solutions from many different websites and sources, including [this book](https://books.google.fi/books?id=UjWoIFHcr58C&pg=PT188&lpg=PT188&dq=setopenglcontext%20opencv&source=bl&ots=Sae6Dzru0B&sig=gZ2_kAE9opaiJbq9pJ-oOlK6BDg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQx5Cw06rbAhUKEJoKHch2DsMQ6AEIaDAG#v=onepage&q=setopenglcontext%20opencv&f=false). Program works as expected in every manner, except that openglcallback never gets called. All the help is much appreciated.

Comment: I found out the cause, `cv::imshow()` prevents opengl usage. I will update this question and answer as I find out more details.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. so as I yesterday found out, `cv::imshow` prevented me from using OpenGL commands on that window.

So what I had to do to overcome this, was to read the data on a `cv::Mat`, just like before. But instead of rendering that `cv::Mat` straight on the window using `cv::imshow`, I had to first store the data on a texture and then render that texture on screen. To store the data on a texture I used the following method:

```
/**
*texture: Pointer to OpenGL texture that we want to render our stream on.
*data: cv::Mat that contains the data we want to render.
**/
void storeStreamToTexture(GLuint texture, cv::Mat* data){
    //Bind the texture we want to render to.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    //we flip the Mat to start reading from the beginning.
    cv::flip(*data, *data, 0);
    //Store mat data to our texture.
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, data->cols, data->rows, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data->data);
}
```

And after that we can use our texture like we would use any other texture on OpenGL. Hope someone finds this useful in the future! :)